# How to manage interface in the right way

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interface like this:

```
export interface Folder {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  date: Date;
}
```

but in the real context date the JSON response give me a string type. What's the best way to manage this kind of data between back-end and front-end? I need to define two interfaces? One with date of type string and another one with type Date?

Comment: One option is [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), e.g. https://tsplay.dev/wX2dQm.

Answer (score 2):

I probably would have done something like:

```js
interface BaseFolder {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}

export interface RawFolder extends BaseFolder {
  date: string;
}

export interface Folder extends BaseFolder {
  date: Date;
}
```

So inside an http call you can use them like:

```js
this.http.get<RawFolder>(/* path */).pipe(map(rawFolder => /* logic to transform your raw folder in a real folder*/));
```